# Force running a codeception test before another

Tags: testing, codeception

If i define an `@depends annotation` like below, the test cannot be run if the createObjectBase Test has not run successfully before.

Sometimes i don't want to run the whole suite, but only the createObjectGeo Test.
How can i define that if i run createObjectGeo, codeception runs createObjectBase before it?

```
/**
 * 
 */   
 public function createObjectBase  (AcceptanceTester $I) {
 }


/**
 * @depends createObjectBase  
 */   
 public function createObjectGeo(AcceptanceTester $I) {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you should looking for the `@before/@after` annotations for this functionality

```
/**
 * 
 */   
 public function createObjectBase  (AcceptanceTester $I) {
 }


/**
 * @before createObjectBase
 */   
 public function createObjectGeo(AcceptanceTester $I) {
 }
```

please take a look at the documentation http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#BeforeAfter-Annotations

The tests will be executed in the same order they will be written in the Cest file.

Comment: I tried that, but if i run the whole suite it triggers createObjectBase twice. First time because its the first test and then because of the @before.

Comment: Try to make the first method protected or private. Than codeception didn't call the method as a test.

Comment: sounds interesting, will try it later.